# Error when trying to change Jenkins default configuration directory using a Tomcat server installed on Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, tomcat, server

I'm doing a tutorial to learn more about adminsys and services on linux. I arrived to a chapter about Tomcat and Jenkins. It's about installing jenkins as a Tomcat servlet. I was following the instructions and I ran into trouble when I tried to change Jenkins default configuration directory like advised in the tutorial.

1. Ok so I first installed tomcat alone and the default web page showed up like expected at http://www.example.com:8080/
2. I downloaded jenkins using : `wget https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.361.2/jenkins.war`
3. I moved the .war file in `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps` using : `sudo mv jenkins.war /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps`

Now it's where it gets tricky : the tutorial says that Jenkins puts the configurations, logs and builds files in `/root/.jenkins/` by default and advises to change that to put them in `/var/lib/jenkins/`.

1. To do that, I first created the directory : `sudo mkdir /var/lib/jenkins`
2. I changed the permissions so that tomcat can access it, using : `sudo chown tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/jenkins`
3. I went into  `/etc/tomcat9/context.xml` . And I added inside the  `<Context />` tags :

```xml
<Context>
    ...
    <Environment name=”JENKINS_HOME” value=”/var/lib/jenkins” type=”java.lang.String” />
</Context>
```

4. I edited tomcat service file `/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service` to avoid read and write problems for jenkins by adding in the sub-section `# Security` of section `[Service]` :

```s
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/jenkins/
```

5. I reloaded the systemd daemon to take the new file service configuration by using `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
6. I reloaded Tomcat : `sudo systemctl restart tomcat9`
7. I went to http://www.example.com:8080/jenkins to access Jenkins installation. I see Jenkins logo but I get an error :

```s
 Error
Unable to create the home directory ‘/var/lib/tomcat/.jenkins’. This is most likely a permission problem.

To change the home directory, use JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set the JENKINS_HOME system property. See Container-specific documentation for more details of how to do this.
```

Obviously there is a permission problem, but I can't find the problem, my knowledge is too small on these technologies and on linux. In the video tutorial, the teacher does exactly what I did and everything worked perfectly. I searched a lot on stackoverflow and google but couldn't exactly find something similar.

Still, it's weird that jenkins wants to create the home directory at `/var/lib/tomcat/.jenkins` as I specified to create it in `/var/lib/jenkins`. So it looks like that, maybe, even if I restarted and reloaded all, what I've changed haven't been taken into consideration.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get around the problem thanks to the message indicating the creation of the `.jenkins` in the `/var/lib/tomcat` directory instead of `/var/lib/jenkins` as specified in the `context.xml` configuration file.

When you look in the `/etc/passwd` file, a *tomcat* user is present with `/var/lib/tomcat` as home directory. I simply changed this path to `/var/lib/jenkins`.

Then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`  and  `sudo systemctl restart tomcat9` and it worked for me.

I found no other solution on stackoverflow and google either.
I still don't unsterdand why *tomcat daemon* does not take into account the `context.xml` file and prefers its own home directory to install jenkins.
If someone has a cleaner solution I am interested.